# Instantiating C# 9 Records from F#

Tags: f#

If I have a C# 9 record defined:

```cs
public record Reading
{
    public long Timestamp { get; init; }
    public float TemperatureCelsius { get; init; }
}
```

How do I instantiate it from F# (5.01)?

```ml
let newReading () =
   // ???
```

It feels like it should be simple, but I can't seem to get it to work.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I created two projects, both using .NET Core 5.0:

- CSharpProj: C# 9 class library
- FSharpProj: F# 5 console app

Instantiating the C# record from F# works fine for me, if I treat it like a normal class type:

```
open CSharpProj
let reading = Reading()
```

However, I'm unable to successfully set either `Timestamp` or `TemperatureCelsius` from F#. It looks like [F# doesn't understand C# init setters yet](https://github.com/fsharp/fslang-suggestions/issues/904). The following attempt compiles fine:

```
let reading = Reading(Timestamp = 1L, TemperatureCelsius = 1.0f)
```

But generates an `InvalidProgramException` at runtime. I assume the F# team will address this problem at some point. In the meantime, as a work-around, I changed the C# record type to:

```
public record Reading(long Timestamp, float TemperatureCelsius)
{
}
```

And now the same invocation from F# successfully sets the two properties.

Comment: The link you provided was useful. I tried searching there for C# 9 records from F# but it returned irrelevant results. So I thought since both are on .NET 5, they would have worked. Cheers!